# How to display page title in the divi text module

Tags: wordpress, divi

I am trying to add a mailto link to a page created with divi builder.
I've added a text module in Divi builder with the following content:

```
Some text... then please write an email to: <a href="mailto:email@email.com?subject=Please help with " target="_blank" rel="noopener">email@email.com</a>
```

After "Please help with" I need to insert page title. I've tried `<?php echo $product->post->post_title; ?>` and `<?php echo woocommerce_template_single_title(); ?>` but no luck so far, it just breaks the page. So my final attempt looked like this:

```
Some text... then please write an email to: <a href="mailto:email@email.com?subject=Please help with <?php echo $product->post->post_title; ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener">email@email.com</a>
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page title, you would use `the_title()`. You can create a shortcode and use that shortcode in the Divi builder. That may be cleaner.

```
function namespace_post_title() {
   $title = get_the_title();
   return $title;
}
add_shortcode( 'namespace_show_title', 'namespace_post_title' );
```

Then in the Divi builder, use the shortcode we just created:

```
[namespace_show_title]
```